# How do I reuse ResolveField in different Resolvers?

Tags: nestjs, nestjs-graphql

In my app, I have `priority` field which has it's own resolver.
That `priority` field is used in `technology`. Something like this:

```
type Technology {
  id: Int!
  name: String!
  priority: Priority!
}

type Priority {
  id: Int!
  name: String!
}
```

So in `technologies` resolver I have

```
@ResolveField(() => Priority, { name: 'priority' })
  getPriority(
    @Parent()
    technology: TechnologyParent
  ) {
      ...
```

However, then I also have another resolver called `columns` which has this

```
@ResolveField(() => [Technology], { name: 'technologies' })
```

From what I understood, because I already have

```
@ResolveField(() => Priority, { name: 'priority' })
```

under `technologies` resolver, I don't need to do anything. But is this a correct wy of "sharing" `ResolveField`?